# Из C++ в Delphi

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста перевести код из C++ в Delphi

```
int virtual_code = MapVirtualKeyA(scancode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK);
LPARAM lp = scancode << 16 | 1;
PostMessageA(wnd, WM_KEYDOWN, virtual_code, lp);
Sleep(25);
lp = 1 << 31 | 1 << 30 | scancode << 16 | 1;
PostMessageA(wnd, WM_KEYUP, virtual_code, lp);
```

Comment: здесь все неизвестные для вас типы это целые числа. 

оператор | это побитовое ИЛИ. 

оператор << побитовый сдвиг в лево. 

оператор = это присваивание. 

оператор ; это конец выражения. 

имена выделенные сиреневым цветом это имена функций, между скобками параметры функции

Comment: самое непонятное было в символах "<<", остальное-то просто(

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот сайт — не бюро переводов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бегло переводить, то где то так

```
var
  virtual_code:integer;
  lp:LPARAM;
begin
  //....
  virtual_code := MapVirtualKeyA(scancode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK);
  lp := (scancode shl 16) or 1;
  PostMessageA(wnd, WM_KEYDOWN, virtual_code, lp);
  Sleep(25);
  lp := (1 shl 31) or (1 shl 30) or (scancode shl 16) or 1;
  PostMessageA(wnd, WM_KEYUP, virtual_code, lp);
  //.......
end
```

функции `MapVirtualKeyA` и `PostMessageA` - это стандартные, возможно Вам нужно будут без суффикса А (в самом конце). Также я не уверен на счет константы `MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK`.